# Django - Concat two fields in a Many to Many Relation to search for a string

Tags: mysql, django, many-to-many

I'm using Django 3.2.6 and Mysql.

I have two models

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

class Book(models.Model):

```
...
author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name="authors")
```

A Book can have multiple authors and an author can have multiple books. Now I want to write a simple search where users should be able to search using the Author name.

Since I will be using this search in different parts of the App, I created a Custom Manager added the following function.

```
def search(self, keyword):
        return (
            self
                .filter(
                Q(title__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(description__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(isbn__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(category__name__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(author__first_name__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(author__last_name__icontains=keyword)
            )
            .annotate(book_count=Count("id"))
            .order_by("-id")
    )
```

Please note that  *`annotate(book_count=Count("id"))`* this part is important otherwise it will return duplicate rows if a book has multiple Authors.

This works if I'm searching only using first_name or last_name. For example, it will return results if I search "John" or "Smith". But if I Search full name like "John Smith" this will not return any result.

So after searching, I modified the function as follows

```
def search(self, keyword):
        return (
            self
                .annotate(
                    full_name=Concat(
                    "author__first_name", Value(" "), "author__last_name",
                    output_filed=CharField()
                ))
                .filter(
                Q(title__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(description__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(isbn__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(category__name__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(author__first_name__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(author__last_name__icontains=keyword)
                | Q(full_name__icontains=keyword)
            )
            .annotate(book_count=Count("id"))
            .order_by("-id")
        )
```

But now I'm getting the following error

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'author.first_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")
```

How can I solve this? Is this the right approach? I'm able to retrieve the proper results using a raw query. But Can is it possible to implement in django-way.

Comment: Drop the `.annotate(book_count=Count('id'))` and work with `.distinct()` instead.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but now I'm getting duplicate results. i.e if a book has two authors, it will be shown multiple times